# CSS: How to vertically align elements inside div with display: table-cell

Tags: css

I want to vertically align two buttons and a span inside a div. The div has:

```
display: table-cell
```

I have no idea how to do it. I have this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xbkr17xn/) and as you 
can see the elements are aligned horizontally. I need them to 
be aligned vertically.

How can i do that?

Comment: Already vertically aligned in Firefox and Chrome. http://prntscr.com/8972ja

Comment: dont know what you mean. i posted a jsfiddle. its not vertically aligend. in the link you posted they arent vertically aligned as well. I guess you missunderstood the question.

Comment: Do you want all the elements to have a stacking effect?

Comment: dont know what a static effect is. I just want the 2 buttons and the span to be vertically aligned and not horizontally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default display value of the buttons is `display: inline-block`.

Set the buttons to have `display: block` to cover the full width and align them to center with `margin: 0 auto`.

```css
.postcard-left-menu {
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #57D5B8;
}
.postcard-left-menu-buttons {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
.postcard-left-menu-buttons .button {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.postcard-left-menu-buttons span {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="postcard-left-menu">
  <div class="postcard-left-menu-buttons">
    <button class="button">-</button>
    <span>1</span>
    <button class="button">+</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Mulgard No problem! :)